# Database/data storage for high volume of simple transactions

Tags: database, data-structures, file-io, filesystems

I have written a PHP application which requires storage of millions of integers between 0 and 10,000,000 inclusive. Each number is incremented by one very frequently (on average 100 values are updated every second) and read very frequently (20,000 reads per second). The numbers are reset to 0 either nightly, weekly, monthly or annually.

I've got a fairly good handle on MySQL but it feels like overkill, and not very efficient in the process.

Has anyone had to deal with this before, and/or could shed some light on a suitable data storage system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how much memory you have, and how long you have to keep them around - you could just use the APC cache, or memcache. memcache has a nice increment operation, so it's crazy efficient doing it.

BTW, you said you need 20K reads. And you are doing it in PHP? on one server or on a cluster? Sounds like you need some architectural guidance..... :)

If it's a web-app, you are going to be using a cluster. And if it's not a web app, I'd suggest you think about re-doing it in something which isn't PHP. Java, C++ and c# come to mind.

Comment: Holy wow memcache looks perfect. Thanks man I'll try porting over!

Yep it's a web app. It's on a VPS(!) for testing. After memcache is kicking butt I want to ditch Apache for something a bit leaner. Then I'll split data requests across IP addresses and bring new servers up when needed. I think. :-)

Comment: Just spotted you're based in London - were you at hackday or BCL6?

Comment: No, I wasn't at either hackday or BCL6. Maybe consider using Amazon EC2, so you can make an image of your base setup and then just bring it up, run a script (maybe pull from svn etc) and you have the new machine :) easy :)